# Como obter o nome de todas as classes do usuário?

Tags: php, classes

A função [`get_declared_classes`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-declared-classes.php) pega **TODAS** as classes definidas no PHP, tanto da biblioteca interna do PHP, como as do usuário.

Eu queria uma função para classes do tipo: [`get_defined_functions`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-defined-functions.php), que separa funções do núcleo PHP de funções do usuário.

Creio que dá pra fazer com [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.reflection.php) mas acredito que exista outra opção.

Como pegar classes definidas pelo **usuário** no PHP?

Comment: Tem uns comentários na documentação dizendo que se você usar a função antes de declarar a classe, ela não irá aparecer na lista, dai poderia fazer um _diff_ dos resultados, mas eu testei e aparece mesmo antes de declara-la...

Comment: Seria melhor fazer um log no seu loader.

Comment: Eu tentei um teste aqui com `array_diff(get_declared_classes(), spl_classes())`, mas algumas classes nativas foram retornadas

Comment: Pegar todas as classes do usuário é muito comum em frameworks, mas eles percorrem os diretórios abrindo e tokentizando os arquivos para pegar os nomes das classes. Se tiver interesse posso postar uma resposta mostrando como fazer

Comment: As vezes se falar o objetivo de querer obter as classes definidas pelo usuário, podem surgir maneiras mais praticas para conseguir o que precisa. Para que precisa disso?

Comment: Preciso para questões sobre debug... (informações).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Até agora não achei outro jeito:

Dá pra fazer por Reflection:

```
        $classes = get_declared_classes();

        foreach($classes as $className){
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($className);

            if( $reflection->isUserDefined() ){
                echo $className.'<br>';
            }
        }
```